# Native Library in java using eclipse

Tags: java, dll, native

Please let me know how to use `Native Lib.` in Eclipse.
for more:
I am using `AspriseOCR.dll` in our project for image processing.
but sys can't find this dll file in java library path.
i am getting below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no AspriseOCR in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1682)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1030)
    at com.readimage.ReadIMG.main(ReadIMG.java:37)
```

Comment: I got the same error, followed the steps mentioned in the below 1st answer, but did not solved my problem. Pls someone guide me on this..

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem. It was resolved by putting below .dll into ../java(version)/jre/bin folder:

AspriseOCR.dll, AspriseJTwain.dll, DevIL.dll, ILU.dll

Vishal Srivastava

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the dll path into your System path. you can use following code to add dll file into your system path

```
    System.setProperty( "java.library.path", "DriveName:/native/dll-folder/" );
    Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField( "sys_paths" );
    fieldSysPath.setAccessible( true );
    fieldSysPath.set( null, null );
```

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: AspriseOCR
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1882)
 at com.readimage.ReadIMG.main(ReadIMG.java:33)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no AspriseOCR in java.library.path
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1682)
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1030)
 at com.asprise.util.ocr.OCR.loadLibrary(OCR.java:247)
 at com.asprise.util.ocr.OCR.<init>(OCR.java:56)
 at com.readimage.ReadIMG.main(ReadIMG.java:49)
----- getting this error.

Comment: I had same problem when i was working with OCR native lib.
just put "AspriseOCR.dll" to your C:/programs files/java(version)/jre/bin folder..
and check.. i hope it'll work properly :-)